# Thunderbird Importing Emails imports 0 emails

Tags: wordpress, email, thunderbird

I'm trying to import emails that I backed up from my wordpress website's hosted email on hostgator. The backup file is a mail.zip file. How can I import the emails using the file I have using Thunderbird? Or is there any other way that I could achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

I have tried importing it using Thunderbird it shows 0 emails imported.

Comment: Safest way is to connect to your email trough Thunderbird with sync which will download all emails (time depends on quantity of emails). If you no longer have access to this email then zip files with size over 2gb are not supported - https://support.mozilla.org/bg/kb/thunderbird-import - use Import from another Thunderbird installation in step 1 and then select Choose a profile folder in step 2 of the import.